# Speed up S3 files copy between buckets-Using python

Tags: python, file, amazon-s3, copy, boto3

All, I am trying to copy large number of files from one bucket to other, following is my code but looks like copy is not happening! Not sure does bot3.transfer has copy method.

what I am missing here

```
            import os
            import boto3
            import botocore
            import boto3.s3.transfer as s3transfer
            from boto3.session import Session
            
            
            clients3 = boto3.client('s3',
                                    aws_access_key_id='',
                                    aws_secret_access_key='')
            
            bucketname = 'source_buckets'
            PREFIX = "folder1/folder2/202204"
            destbucket = 'destination_bucket'
            
            output = clients3.list_objects(Bucket=bucketname, Prefix=PREFIX)
            
            files_src = [folder['Key'] for folder in output['Contents']]
            file_dest = [destbucket + '/' + f.split('/')[2] for f in files_src]
            
            
            botocore_config = botocore.config.Config(max_pool_connections=20)
            s3client = boto3.client('s3', config=botocore_config)
            transfer_config = s3transfer.TransferConfig(
                use_threads=True,
                max_concurrency=20,
            )
            s3t = s3transfer.create_transfer_manager(s3client, transfer_config)
            
            
            for src, dest in zip(files_src, file_dest):
                copy_source = {'Bucket': bucketname,
                               'key': src
                               }
                s3t.copy(copy_source=copy_source,
                         bucket=destbucket,
                         key=dest.split('/')[1]
                         )
```

Comment: Are you calling shutdown to let the TransferManager complete all work items?

Comment: no , I didn't add that code. let me add and respond to this thread,

Comment: added s3t.shutdown() at the end of script.. but don't see any copy happening , code is just existing quickly with no error.